# Handling methods/return from function without running the function every time?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

firstly thank you in advance for reading. I have looked everywhere and I am very new to Javascript and trying to understand how best to handle this specific issue.

```
function first() {

var string = "1,2,3,4,5";

function second(payload){

//in here is a bunch of code that prepares what I need to happen

    randomcode = payload.split(",")[1] + payload.split(",")[0];

    testarray = {
      one: payload.split(",")[0],
      two: payload.split(",")[1],
      three: payload.split(",")[2],
      code: randomcode
      };

      return testarray;  
 }

console.log(second(string).one,second(string).two,second(string).three,second(string).code); 

}

first();
```

[JS Bin Example](https://jsbin.com/cexodogide/edit?js,console)

The code I am actually writing is for a web endpoint which gets a JSON which I then parse and prepare to post to a google sheet (this is being written in GAS). What I would like to do, for efficiency, is to return the equivalent result shown in 'second(string).code' without running second() every time as the code I have written is quite lengthy. I have considered creating the array as global but this will make life harder for when the JSON is modified.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this? I appreciate this is a bit ugly and may not be the right approach for JSON but I am learning in small steps and any help appreciated :)

Comment: Firstly your emulating JSON is not correct, it should either be `'[1,2,3,4]'` or `'"1,2,3,4"'`  Otherwise your just using a comma separated list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow & Javascript. You can try to assign the output from second() to a variable. Then it won't execute repeatedly. Please check below code. Also moving the second function out will make your code bit more efficient.

```js
function second(payload){

//in here is a bunch of code that prepares what I need to happen

    randomcode = payload.split(",")[1] + payload.split(",")[0];

    testarray = {
      one: payload.split(",")[0],
      two: payload.split(",")[1],
      three: payload.split(",")[2],
      code: randomcode
      };

      return testarray;  
 }

function first() {

var string = "1,2,3,4,5";

var secondOut = second(string);

console.log(secondOut.one,secondOut.two,secondOut.three,secondOut.code); 

}

first();
```